# Display div based on option selected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have 3 options here

```
<select id="adtype" name="adtype" onchange="validate();">
<option id="banner" value="ban">Banner Advertisement</option>
<option id="textr" value="txt">Text Advertisement</option>
<option id="log" value="log">Login Advertisement</option>
</select>
```

I need to display 3 divisions, 1 division per option when each option is selected
suppose when banner is selected,banner division is displayed
but all the divisions must be in same position in the page .
My javascript code is:

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    var ddl = document.getElementById("adtype");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "selectoption")
    {
        alert("Please select an Advert type");
    }
    if(selectedValue == "txt")
    {
        document.getElementById("ban").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("textadvert").style.display="block";
    }
}
</script>`
```

My javascript code is not doing the work please anyone can make it posible.

Comment: And the question is?  Also, do indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this codepen for you which does not require a new if for every div you got (useful if you want to add more)

HTML difference: "display-ban" ID instead of just "ban" because you had a conflict on the "log" ID, and this one might be more specific.

```
<div class="hidden" id="display-ban">BAN DIV</div>
```

JS main difference:

```
var subjectDiv=document.getElementById("display-"+selectedValue)
subjectDiv.style.display="block";
```

Also I made a check for the previously displayed item, and hide it.

```
if(prev){
 prev.style.display="none";
}
```

Hope this helps. You can find the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/JKNgYY?editors=1111).

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working because the `id` of the elements do not match.

```
function validate() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("adtype");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

  if (selectedValue == "selectoption") {
    alert("Please select an Advert type");
  }

  if(selectedValue == "txt") {  
    document.getElementById("banner").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("textr").style.display="block";
  }
}
```

Your `id`s are adtype, banner, textr and log whereas you're checking against an `id` of ban and textadvert.

Comment: no i am checking the values please see var selectedValue

Comment: i want to hide banner division and display textadvert div in place of it

Comment: look at this line in you code `document.getElementById("ban").style.display="none"`. you are searcing for an id `ban` which should be `banner` since your option has an id `banner`.

Comment: yes i am searching for id but checking against value of options please solve this problem